# iOS - programmatic modal segue with animation (such as flip)

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, segue, flip

I know I can do a modal segue in code like this:

```
[presentModalViewController:my_view, animated:YES];
```

but how do I specify a fade in or horizontal/vertical flip programmatically?

Thanks,
Pachun

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set this property to your viewController:  `modalTransitionStyle`

**UIModalTransitionStyle** from apple doc

```
  typedef enum { UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0, 
                 UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
                 UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,  
                  UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```