# Tab Bar Item shows View Controller with modal segue

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uitabbaritem

I have a TabBarController with 5 TabBarItems (build with IB). So far, so good. But, when I tap the second item for example, I want that my second view controller appear with a modal segue. I don’t understand the way to fix it with a TabBarController…

Anyone could help me please ?

Comment: Have you tried this?
-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901006/ios-programmatic-modal-segue-with-animation-such-as-flip

Answer (score 1):

Would it help if you subclassed the tab bar controller and implemented your own segue transitions where appropriate?

Specify the delegates `UITabBarControllerDelegate`
in your `UITabBarController` subclass and implement the function

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
```

to trap the selection.

Create a transition that inherits from `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` using a custom Class and use this to display and hide the tab as and when necessary.